# Grafana- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')

Tags: automated-tests, grafana, influxdb, flux, grafana-alerts

When i try to `Set a query and alert condition` under the alert role I keep getting the below error. I search other blogs could not able to resolve this issue

```
An unexpected error happened
Details
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'values')

    at ni (http://localhost:3000/public/build/AlertingRuleForm.f65c22acec748d21665e.js:145:233)
    at div
    at de (http://localhost:3000/public/build/9512.8f35f1c2de682ecc2973.js:2:92536)
    at li (http://localhost:3000/public/build/AlertingRuleForm.f65c22acec748d21665e.js:252:28)
    at div
    at de
```

Query i was using:

```
from(bucket:"API_BE")
    |> range(start: -15m)
    |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "3 API competition")
    |> yield()
```

Grafana Version: `9.3.2`
(DataSource)Influx Db version: `v2.6.0`

I am running grafana and influxd in local machine(Windows:10)